# How to homebrew legally in South Africa?

Tags: brewing

I enjoy brewing and the challenges involved. I am self taught and rather good with my sweet beers.

I am South-African and want to know how to go legal and if it is worth the costs  and challenges invloved.

Comment: I have absolutely no relevant knowledge for you, but I wish you luck!

Comment: You need a liquor license to sell alcohol though.

Comment: Please remember to mark an answer, or comment if you feel you need more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a South African homebrewer I can happily report that it is legal to brew in South Africa. We have no legal limitation on what/how much we may brew. The only rule is: **Do not sell your brewed product!**

There are a few homebrew shops around, Beerguevera, brewmart, black kilt, etc. Google should help you find a good one close by.

Ask your questions on homebrew.stackexchange.com

For a active SA Brewing forum: wortsandall.co.za

There is a home brew club in most provinces. On wortandall you can find one close to you.

Better get brewing fast! The Nationals are starting soon! :D

Happy Brewing!

Answer (score 6):

It is legal to home brew beers in unlimited quantities for personal use only.
You may not for sell it without the required required permits or licenses. Registration as a "manufacturer not for commercial use" at the South African Revenue Service (SARS) is required to produce wine at home.

Happy brewing from a fellow home brewer in Cape Town